# Autocad VBA - Create Square

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

I'm trying to make a simple square in AutoCAD using VBA but when I try to run my code I get an "Out of Range" Error? Any help would be great!

```
Sub box()
'Link the Exel File to the open CAD File'
'If no CAD file open it does create one'
'----------------------------------------------------------------'
Dim ACAD As AcadApplication 'Create ACAD variable of type AcadApplication
On Error Resume Next 'This tells VBA to ignore errors
Set ACAD = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application") 'Get a running instance of the class AutoCAD.Application
On Error GoTo 0 'This tells VBA to go back to NOT ignoring errors
If ACAD Is Nothing Then 'Check to see if the above worked
    Set ACAD = New AcadApplication 'Set the ACAD variable to equal a new instance of AutoCAD
    ACAD.Visible = True 'Once loaded, set AutoCAD® to be visible
End If
ACAD.ActiveDocument.Utility.Prompt "Hello from Excel!" 'Print a message to the AutoCAD® command line

Dim squareObj As Acad3DSolid
Dim center(0 To 2) As Double

center(0) = 10
center(1) = 10
center(2) = 0

Set squareObj = ACAD.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddBox(center, 2, 2, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: you do not have `center`  ... you have `center(0)` ... etc

Comment: if that is the problem, then delete this post. it is not really any help to anyone else

Comment: The first argument is fine.  The `origin` (aka `center`) is supposed to be a `Variant (three-element array of doubles);`

Comment: First off, what version of AutoCAD are you using? I tried it from excel and got an Automation Error(Acad 2014).  It works fine in AutoCAD.  So I think it's some kind of security/trust issue, since you are accessing AutoCAD using an ActiveX/Com interface.  It'll be a lot faster, with less issues if you use C#.Net I think.

Comment: @Profex Your suggestion could very well be the cause for OPs issue; however, if he uses a .NET add-in to perform tasks, he will still need to do the same trusted/security measures as he would with a script.  This simply involves ensuring that where ever you are running scripts/dlls from on your machine is defined as a 'Trusted Location' under the options dialog of AutoCAD.

Comment: @hilli_micha I'm not sure if I new that before and forgot, but I'll have to test it out if I get a chance.  Usually I just write my VBA code in AutoCAD and ask the user for the excel file(s) to process.  Still, I think C or C#.Net was like 200x faster then VBA back in ACAD 2012.

Comment: try: `Set squareObj = ACAD.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddBox(center, 2, 2, 4)` box height=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Autodesk

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-DE469E81-8531-415C-9D22-7041A42838DD-htm.html

```
RetVal = object.AddBox(Origin, Length, Width, Height)
```

The height of the box. Must be a positive number since it seems like autocad won't create a 3d solid with zero height.